# Build Failed - Non-Zero Exit Code Detected after 'yarn build' in AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, vite

I created a project with `vite --template react-ts` and i can't understand this error

```
2023-03-08T15:11:58.531Z [INFO]: Cloning into 'frontend'...
2023-03-08T15:11:58.532Z [INFO]: # Checking for Git submodules at: /codebuild/output/src389073204/src/frontend/.gitmodules
2023-03-08T15:11:58.540Z [INFO]: # Retrieving environment cache...
2023-03-08T15:11:58.585Z [WARNING]: ! Unable to write cache: {"code":"ERR_BAD_REQUEST","message":"Request failed with status code 404"})}
2023-03-08T15:11:58.586Z [INFO]: ---- Setting Up SSM Secrets ----
2023-03-08T15:11:58.586Z [INFO]: SSM params {"Path":"/amplify/d1h59jjie2t1ia/main/","WithDecryption":true}
2023-03-08T15:11:58.613Z [WARNING]: !Failed to set up process.env.secrets
2023-03-08T15:12:10.042Z [INFO]: # Node version 18 is available for installation
2023-03-08T15:12:10.190Z [INFO]: # Installing Node version 18
2023-03-08T15:12:14.913Z [INFO]: # Now using Node version 18
2023-03-08T15:12:14.995Z [INFO]: # Retrieving cache...
2023-03-08T15:12:15.038Z [INFO]: # Retrieved cache
2023-03-08T15:12:17.484Z [INFO]: ## Starting Backend Build
                                 ## Checking for associated backend environment...
                                 ## No backend environment association found, continuing...
2023-03-08T15:12:17.484Z [INFO]: ## Completed Backend Build
2023-03-08T15:12:17.486Z [INFO]: ## Starting Frontend Build
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
2023-03-08T15:12:17.486Z [INFO]: # Executing command: yarn install
2023-03-08T15:12:17.511Z [WARNING]: node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
                                    node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
2023-03-08T15:12:17.512Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-03-08T15:12:17.512Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-03-08T15:12:17.512Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-03-08T15:12:17.512Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

My compilation settings

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: dist/
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

I tried changing the build location and changing the application name in amplify, as well as changing the node version

Comment: If it is failing to build the front-end, see if you can build is locally first, before sending it to AWS Amplify

Comment: @felipe I have a similar sequence of warnings and errors. Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: My build locally is working, I still can't solve the problem =/

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem yet, I uploaded it to netlify. We identified that VITE needs to access environment variables during build time, but we haven't worked on a solution for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should try to put the same version of your local node with the command node -v

[image: Get the local version of node.js]

2. Set up the same local node version of node in AWS Amplify

   - Click on your app in amplify
   - At the right side click in Build settings
   - Click on edit in Build image settings section
   - Add package version of node [image: add package version of node]
3. Try again to redeploy